# Send notification to users in restricted area

Tags: notifications, geolocation, google-cloud-messaging

I'm looking for the way to use GCM (or FCM) to send downstream message to devices but instead of restrict my destination group by topic subscriber, I need to limit it by device location.

For example, I give a `Circle` object as destination group like `Circle(latlng, radius)` and it automatically trigger the message to devices in this area.

I seen in the [FCM/GCM documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support) a field that can may help me, but I don't understand their definition:

> **body_loc_key**: Indicates the key to the body string for **localization**. Corresponds to "loc-key" in the APNs payload.
>
> **body_loc_args** :Indicates the string value to replace format specifiers in the body string for **localization**.

What do they mean by "for localization"? Is there a simple way to send a 'geonotification'?

Thanks for help

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956366/location-based-push-notifications-for-android), it might give you an idea on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks that's look to be a good strategy

Comment: One way would be to use the location APIs on the device to alert when the user moves in and out of the "circle" then have the app subscribe to or unsubscribe from a topic corresponding to that circle. Then when you send to that topic only devices in the "circle" would receive the message

Comment: Thanks Arthur but this is only in a case where my circle is something a little static but when i have in what ever time a notification to send to anywhere in the world (and more than 100 different place request by hour) it will be difficult to do.