# How to Track a Specific User from some Identifier in Xamarin Forms from Web Application with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, xamarin, xamarin.forms

all
in this thread, i will ask about tracking system for xamarin forms.
the system use 2 service, 1 used ASP.NET service with Entity Framework, Odata for Web Application and the other one asp.net Core Service, and xamarin.forms for mobile application, the specific application for mobile is android which used by more than 200 user.
the question is,

1. is Push Notification can track the mobile apps after on click event? if yes, how can i Track the specific user from Web Application after on click event in WebApplication ?

any link or any idea should be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What did you mean by ` "can track the mobile apps after on click event"`, what do you want to track? If you mean `User activity`, `user action during login into the app` then yes you can do that using `User Session`

Comment: i mean, track xamarin mobile application (android) after click in web application like asp.net web application.

Comment: In that case I think you can set the additional request header on the each request comes from your app to the asp.net backend, so that it can be track from where the request coming from.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron i hope u can refer to this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956366/location-based-push-notifications-for-android/29956521
as i`m use Xamarin Application.